# Replacement for Linear Potentiometer

Tags: communication, passive-components

A rotary encoder replaces a rotary potentiometer, while providing a long live due to no wiper degrading the substrate.

How can I replace a linear potentiometer (a "fader") with something following the same fashion ?

Background :

I have a certain appliance that has DSP equalization internally. I can change the coefficients via i2c. I want to keep the usual "equalizer" visual and feeling, by using pots, but, in order to get something more modern, i wanted to replace the usual linear slider analog pots for linear encoders, read them using a microcontroller and send the values via i2c.

Everything is on a box and from outside you cannot tell that everything is being done inside a dsp digitally. It looks and feels like a old school equalizer...

Comment: You can go for linear absolute encoder(pretty hard to find though). Or you can build one yourself.

Comment: found nothing, but linear encoders that are too big and costly to replace a simple linear potentiometer...

Comment: Quadrature Linear Encoders? Or you can do Inductive/Capacitive as well.

Comment: nothing that readily replaces a potentiometer

Comment: I don't think there is a ready solution without tweaking any of your hardware. If Linear pots were replaced by ready to throw-in solutions which lasted more; people would do that.

Comment: You have not explained your problem very well. What resolution do you require, is it an audio (as in signal) attenuation application etc etc. If what you want is to replace an existing linear potentiometer in a piece of equipment then you have to design something to take its place. A rotary encoder is not like a potentiometer in any way, it provides an angular displacement signal (incremental or absolute). Likewise a digital potentiometer can proved a resistive output, but requires digital signals to set it to a position.

Comment: its not really a potentiometer, but, provided a digital pot ic and some logic it can work like one. but i cand find something that replaces pots on an equalizer (sliders etc).

Comment: Linear position encoders (common in printers, but can also be used in digital faders, typically optical but may also be Hall-effect) are a good choice if you want to preserve the traditional feel of a fader. Otherwise you could do a linear capacitive touch element (much more robust, but no physical slider element).

Answer (score 1):

Encoders are not plug in replacements for pots.  If you go with this approach, you will have plenty of embedded work to do.

US digital sells linear encoder strips:  http://www.usdigital.com/products/encoders/incremental/linear/LIN.   You can use any of their encoder readers.

Comment: yeah, after searching a lot i think i will keep the analog pots...

Answer (score 0):

The only linear encoder I know is a LVDT - Linear Variable Differential Transformer. These are AC-excited devices giving a signal proportional to a linear displacement, but they are complex and expensive - gross overkill in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research (From a comment by uint128_t) I found this :

[MagnetoPot](http://www.spectrasymbol.com/product/magnetopot/)

I believe i can hack something by using a small magnet on a slider that traverses over this device. It is still not digital, but at least I believe the durability should be orders of magnitude greater than traditional pots. I am answering just to let other know if in the future they find this question with the same problem.